# IF-THEN vs IF in SAS

Tags: sas

What is the difference between `IF` and `IF-THEN`

For example the following statement

```
if type='H' then output;

vs

if type='H';
output;
```

Comment: The Comparisons section of the SAS documentation on [Subsetting IF Statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/67175/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1cxl8ifdt8u0gn12wqbji8o5fq1.htm) gives details on how the subsetting 'IF' compares to the 'IF-THEN' and 'WHERE' statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An if-then statement conditionally executes code. If the condition is met for a given observation, whatever follows the 'then' before the `;` is executed, otherwise it isn't. In your example, since what follows is `output`, only observations with type `'H'` are output to the data set(s) being built by the data step. You can also have an if-then-do statement, such as in the following code:

```
if type = 'H' then do;
i=1;
output;
end;
```

If-then-do statements conditionally execute code between the `do;` and the `end;`. Thus the above code executes `i=1;` and `output;` only if type equals `'H'`.

An `if` without a `then` is a "subsetting if". According to [SAS documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p04fy20d8il3nfn1ssywe4f25k27.htm):

> A subsetting IF statement tests the condition after an observation is
>   read into the Program Data Vector (PDV). If the condition is true, SAS
>   continues processing the current observation. Otherwise, the
>   observation is discarded, and processing continues with the next
>   observation.

Thus if the condition of a subsetting if (ex. `type='H'`) is not met, the observation is not output to the data set being created by the data step. In your example, only observations where type is `'H'` will be output.

**In summary**, both of your example codes produce the same result, but by different means. `if type='H' then output;` only outputs observations where type is `'H'`, while `if type='H'; output;` discards observations where type is not `'H'`. Note that in the latter you don't need the `output;` because there is an implicit output in the SAS data step, which is only overridden if there is an explicit `output;` command.

Comment: This is mostly correct.  Subsetting `if` does not, technically, prevent output, however; and it does do more than simply prevent output in most situations.  Specifically, subsetting `if` terminates the current iteration of the data step loop and returns to the top of the data step; similar to `if (...) then return`.  This is important because anything that is after the subsetting `if` that is failed does not execute in that row.  Subsetting `if` does prevent the automatic output (as it would prevent the non-automatic `output;` above) but doesn't affect earlier `output` statements.

Answer (score 4):

They're similar but not identical. In a data step, `if` is a subsetting statement, and all records not satisfying the condition are dropped. From the documentation:

"Continues processing only those observations that meet the condition of the specified expression."

`if then` functions more like the `if` statement in other languages, it executes the statement after the `then` clause conditionally. A somewhat contrived example:

```
data baz;
set foo;
if type = 'H';
x = x + 1;
run;

data baz:
set foo;
if type='H' then x = x + 1;
run;
```

In both examples `x` will be incremented by 1 if `type = 'H'`, but in the first data step `baz` will not contain any observations with type not equal to `'H'`.

Nowadays it seems like most things that used to be accomplished by `if` are done using `where`.